# NLog - How to put in a specific log directory

Tags: vb.net, nlog

I am using NLog and would like to use a non-standard directory for logging.  My application, during load, will load a 'LogFileLocation' parameter which stores the location of the logfile directory.

Is it possible to use a non-standard logfile directory?  And, if so, can I also update that in runtime if I have set autoReload="true"?

Comment: Why the non standard location? Is it a PC or Network location you want to save to?

Comment: I guess it doesn't need to be. Just always has been that way with this application.  There will be a service and an application now which will write to the same locations - since they will sit in relatively different directories { /service and /administrator}, then it also might be difficult to have a common location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would just leave the log files for any part of an application in the default location by convention, as that is where other developers will expect it.

I've done something similar with vb.net "Setting" within a WinForms ApplicationEvents to pull a value from the user specific values with mixed results (application upgrades caused issues). At the end of the day that logic doesn't translate well to C#, if that's your kettle of fish.

I assume that you have been through the app.config Nlog [config settings](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target) like the following. I'll assume you can just hardcode the value at the parent app.config level to make it apply to both admin and service components of your application.

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<variable name="logDirectory"
          value="${basedir}/logs/${date:format=yyyyMMdd}/"/>
<targets async="true">
  <target name="AppFullLog"
          layout="${longdate}    ${level:uppercase=true}     ${logger} on ${machinename} by ${windows-identity}.${newline}${message}${newline}Stack:${stacktrace}${newline}-------"
          xsi:type="File"
          fileName="${logDirectory}CadiFull.log">
  </target>
  <target name="AppErrorLog"
          layout="${longdate}    ${level:uppercase=true}     ${logger} on ${machinename} by ${windows-identity}.${newline}${message}${newline}Stack:${stacktrace}${newline}-------"
          xsi:type="File"
          fileName="${logDirectory}CadiErrors.log">
  </target>
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="*"
          writeTo="AppFullLog" />
  <logger name="*"
          levels="Error,Fatal"
          writeTo="AppErrorLog" />
</rules>
```

Finally, if your trying to get all your error logs into one location, you could always send the data to a server database. Nlog provides options to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.  I think I may go with your first suggestion and just NOT change the logfiles directory.  I still have the problem of multiple applications, though.  If I hardcode, then I have a problem if the user decides to use a custom directory upon installation of the software :(